# new subdomain to apply as main domain

Tags: wp-admin, subdomains, domain, site-url

i have 3 subdomains inside my main file manager

```
->web.mysite.com
->web1.mysite.com  (serves as main)
->web2.mysite.com
```

now i want to make web3.mysite.com my main domain. i tried changing wordpress address url in settings of web2 and web1 and its acting weird after that, i cant login to wp-admin anymore thats why i reverted it back through db. cutting the long story short, nothing changes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify some values directly in the database in order to change the url of your primary domain. The values in the following tables needs to be modified:

> wp_options, wp_site, wp_sitemeta, wp_blogs and wp_#_options

Try this [link](https://wpengine.com/support/how-to-change-a-multi-site-primary-domain/) it has all the steps involved in detail

Comment: im sorry but the only table that exists in the list that you've said is wp_options

Comment: since its a multisite some of the tables will be created with the siteid and hence it could be like wp_x_options. So you will need to check and change all these tables as well.